# Animal demography - Single word request

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for 'animal demography'. I would prefer it a single word but I will accept a phrase if no single-words are available.

Comment: Zoology. Doesn't 'demography' only apply to human statistics?

Comment: You sure about zoology? That's the study of animals right? Not the study of the population of animals. And yes, demography only applies to humans. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @JoeDark No, it is standard use in ecology and evolution with regard to both animals and plants, e.g. as in "demographic population model" or "the population demography of Pied flycatchers". "Animal demography" is perfectly fine with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider an uncommon word, there is ***zoography***. It has another sense also but recently, it is being used as animal demography.

> *n.* Now *rare.* L16. [f. ZOO- + -GRAPHY.]
>   Description of animals; descriptive zoology.
>
> Latterly *esp.* a survey of animal populations (cf. DEMOGRAPHY). L16.
>
> http://www.seadict.com/en/en/zoography

---

<sub>*Demo* (in demography) is from Greek *demos* "people". 

*Zoo* (in zoography) is from Greek *zoion* "animal".</sub>

Comment: One word is preferred. Thanks for the answers though.

Comment: For what it is worth, as an ecologist working with demographic population models, I have heard this word a couple of times, and then with a more general meaning than animal demography. I also doubt that many people working with animal demography will label their work as zoography. But whether "zoography" is suitabe maybe depends on who you are writing for.

Comment: @ermanen Sure, feel free if you think that it improves the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Demography is a standard term in ecology and evolution with regard to both animals and plants, so "Animal demography" is perfectly fine to use. Examples of use could be "demographic population model" or "the population demography of Pied flycatchers". You can also see examples by e.g. looking at [text book titles at amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=animal+demography). At the moment, I cannot think of a one-word substitute though.

Answer (score 0):

Demography in the strictest sense refers to characteristics of people.  Demo- means the people!  But, the term is used generically with both animal and plant populations.